# Can Kubernetes manifest rollout status be used with resources without status viewer implementations?

Tags: kubernetes, cicd

I have set up a generic deployment pipeline for applying manifests to a Kubernetes cluster. Following is done in order to verify that the rollout has been successful:

```
kubectl rollout status -f .\manifest.yaml
```

However if the manifest contains resources without status viewer implementations the rollout status command will exit with code 1. Service is a type of resource that does not have the required implementation.

How do I wait for the deployments in a manifest to complete if the manifest contains multiple types of resources?

Letting the manifest only contain the deployment makes the rollout status return code 0 and everything works fine.

Comment: In case someone has this issue in the future I found a workaround for the return code issue. By adding a label selector flag to the rollout status command I can select some label that is only present on the deployment and not on the service: `-l app=DEPLOYMENT_LABEL`